# Does using two JdbcTemplate objects with same DataSource, created within a @Transactional cause transaction issues?

Tags: spring, transactions

I am using Spring Framework 4.x.x. I have a DAO object that makes use of `@Transactional` annotation on a method.  Within this method, a new `JdbcTemplate` is created and some queries are run. Further, within the same method, another `JdbcTemplate` is created and more queries are run.  Both `JdbcTemplate`s use the same `DataSource`.

Is the entire method still a “Transaction?” Or does the second `JdbcTemplate` start it’s own transaction? Or is it that none of the `JdbcTemplate` objects start a transaction? Since `JdbcTemplate` is created within the method and not prior?

Comment: Why you are creating new JdbcTemplate ? Create a bean for that.

Comment: Exactly. I agree with you. I inherited the code and this is what I saw. The person better be happy that I don’t know where he lives!

Comment: So please close the question as you know what you've to do !
At least code duplication for new instance will be removed !
At the end you'll make code more readable, efficient and optimized.

Comment: I could close the question, but it’s not answered. We both agree on what the correct way is. I will try to do more research and run some samples of my own to see how it behaves.  Was wondering if someone with more experience with these kind of things would know off the top of their head.

Comment: If the `JdbcTemplate` instances use the same `DataSource` instance and the `DataSource` instance is bound to a `DataSourceTransactionManager`, the work performed by different `JdbcTemplate` instances involved in the same `@Transactional` context will share the same transaction.

Comment: @manish I will have to check if the DataSource is bound to DataSourceTransactionManager. I will do some reading and update you.